# How do I do a sum of my sum in a subquery for specific IDs?

Tags: sql, sum

I want to do the sum of the total sales into each region. I've tried doing a sum in a subquery but I can't do a sum of that sum afterwards.

```
SELECT   Region.RegionDescription, sq1.[Total sales]
FROM [Order Details]od
INNER JOIN
(SELECT OrderID, SUM(UnitPrice*Quantity)AS [Total sales]
FROM [Order Details]
Group By OrderID)sq1 ON sq1.OrderID=od.OrderID
INNER JOIN
Orders ON od.OrderID = Orders.OrderID 
INNER JOIN
Employees ON Employees.EmployeeID=Orders.EmployeeID
INNER JOIN
EmployeeTerritories ON 
Employees.EmployeeID=EmployeeTerritories.EmployeeID
INNER JOIN
Territories ON Territories.TerritoryID = 
EmployeeTerritories.TerritoryID
INNER JOIN
Region ON Region.RegionID = Territories.RegionID
GROUP BY  Region.RegionDescription, sq1.[Total sales]
```

I expect to see each region with their total sales

Comment: Why are you doing the summation in a sub query instead of the main query, then your group by should work

Comment: My group by works already, it just separates the sums, I've tried it without the subquery and it doesn't work

Comment: Can you change `SELECT   Region.RegionDescription, sq1.[Total sales]` to `SELECT   Region.RegionDescription, sum(sq1.[Total sales])` and have group by look like this `GROUP BY Region.RegionDescription`?

Comment: `SELECT r.RegionDescription, SUM(od.UnitPrice * od.Quantity) FROM [Order Details] od INNER JOIN Orders o ON od.OrderID = o.OrderID INNER JOIN Employees e ON e.EmployeeID=o.EmployeeID INNER JOIN EmployeeTerritories et ON e.EmployeeID=et.EmployeeID INNER JOIN Territories t ON t.TerritoryID = et.TerritoryID INNER JOIN Region r ON r.RegionID = t.RegionID GROUP BY r.RegionDescription` do you get the results you see with this?

Comment: @zedfoxus, that looks like it has worked, thank you so much!!

Comment: Great. I’ll add that as an answer shortly and you can mark that (or another answer) as accepted.

Comment: @CodingHelp123 I've added this as an answer. You are welcome to wait for more answers to arrive. Once you find an answer you feel is appropriate, you can put closure to your question by marking it accepted so that other users can find this as a  solved question.

Comment: Hi, so sorry for another question, i've only had 1 day of sql training. Do you know how I would go about putting a where condition so only total sales over 1000000 would appear in the column?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are two things you could do.

**Remove the subquery**

```
SELECT r.RegionDescription, SUM(od.UnitPrice * od.Quantity)
FROM [Order Details] od
INNER JOIN Orders o ON od.OrderID = o.OrderID
INNER JOIN Employees e ON e.EmployeeID=o.EmployeeID
INNER JOIN EmployeeTerritories et ON e.EmployeeID=et.EmployeeID
INNER JOIN Territories t ON t.TerritoryID = et.TerritoryID
INNER JOIN Region r ON r.RegionID = t.RegionID
GROUP BY r.RegionDescription
```

**Keep subquery**

```
SELECT r.RegionDescription, sum(sq1.[Total sales])
FROM (
    SELECT OrderID, SUM(UnitPrice*Quantity)AS [Total sales]
    FROM [Order Details]
    Group By OrderID
) sq1 ON sq1.OrderID=od.OrderID
INNER JOIN Orders o ON od.OrderID = o.OrderID 
INNER JOIN Employees e ON e.EmployeeID=o.EmployeeID
INNER JOIN EmployeeTerritories et ON e.EmployeeID=et.EmployeeID
INNER JOIN Territories t ON t.TerritoryID = et.TerritoryID
INNER JOIN Region r ON r.RegionID = t.RegionID
GROUP BY r.RegionDescription
```

The first one connects detail records with the rest of the tables. The second one summarizes details to order level and then joins with the rest of the tables. I'd expect performance to be similar. You will have to check for yourself which one runs faster.